# v-on:change method only triggering a get request once (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I am using Vue.js and Choices.js javascript plugin and I have to dynamically populate values of two select fields via ajax.

What I am trying achieve is initate a `get` request at page load and populate the universities select, and after a value in universities select is chosen start a new `get`request to populate the faculties select.

What is happening is that when I pick the university for the first time, everything will work normally. For example if I pick a university option with `value="1"` an ajax get request will be sent to `/faculties?university_id=1`.The console log will print `onChange started`so we are sure the method is running correctly; the appropriate `v-model="selectedUniversity"`is updating too.

If I now change the value of the select field again, the ajax function won't be called anymore and no additional requests will be done to the server. The `console.log`will still run, and the `v-model`is still being updated. Does anyone understand what is going on here?

```js
var Choices = require('choices.js');

  module.exports = {
    data: function() {
      return {
        selectedUniversity: '',
        selectedFaculty: '',
        universities: {},
        faculties: {}
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      var self = this;
      var universitySelect = new Choices(document.getElementById('university'));

      universitySelect.ajax(function(callback) {
        fetch('/universities')
          .then(function(response) {
            response.json().then(function(data) {
              callback(data, 'id', 'name');

                self.universities = data;
            });
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      });

    },
    methods: {
      onChange: function () {
        console.log("onChange started");
        var self = this;
        var url = '/faculties?university_id=' + self.selectedUniversity;
        var facultySelect = new Choices(document.getElementById('faculty'));
        
        //This part below only runs the first time when the university select  is selected

        facultySelect.ajax(function(callback) {
          fetch(url)
            .then(function(response) {
              response.json().then(function(data) {
                callback(data, 'id', 'name');
                  self.faculties = data;
              });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        });

      }
    }
  }
```

The Headers are set like this:

[image]

Comment: What happens to the element with the id faculty when you call new Choices?

Comment: @BertEvans It updates with new values the first time, when the first GET call is made. After that the values from the first call remain populated, obviously, cause none additional get requests are made to the server.

Comment: Yes I understand. I mean, does document.getElementById('faculty') return a value on the second call?

Comment: I suspect the problem is you are initializing a new Choices object every time you change the value when all you want to do is update its options. Typically you would wrap the Choices integration into a component.

Answer (score 1):

I think your request URL `/faculties?university_id=1` is cached and that's why it worked on first time and second time, the response is coming from the cached response.

In your `fetch` API, set cache mode to ignore the cached response,

```
fetch(url, {cache: "no-store"}).then(....)
```

For complete list of `cache` modes for `fetch()` API,
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/03/referrer-and-cache-control-apis-for-fetch/

In case if above link is unavailable,

**Fetch cache control APIs**

The idea behind this API is specifying a caching policy for fetch to explicitly indicate how and when the browser HTTP cache should be consulted.  It’s important to have a good understanding of the HTTP caching semantics in order to use these most effectively.  There are many good articles on the web such as this one that describe these semantics in detail.  There are currently five different policies that you can choose from.

`“default”` means use the default behavior of browsers when downloading resources.  The browser first looks inside the HTTP cache to see if there is a matching request.  If there is, and it is fresh, it will be returned from fetch().  If it exists but is stale, a conditional request is made to the remote server and if the server indicates that the response has not changed, it will be read from the HTTP cache.  Otherwise it will be downloaded from the network, and the HTTP cache will be updated with the new response.

`“no-store”` means bypass the HTTP cache completely. This will make the browser not look into the HTTP cache on the way to the network, and never store the resulting response in the HTTP cache.  Using this cache mode, `fetch()` will behave as if no HTTP cache exists.

`“reload”` means bypass the HTTP cache on the way to the network, but update it with the newly downloaded response.  This will cause the browser to never look inside the HTTP cache on the way to the network, but update the HTTP cache with the downloaded response. Future requests can use that updated response if appropriate.

`“no-cache”` means always validate a response that is in the HTTP cache even if the browser thinks that it’s fresh.  This will cause the browser to look for a matching request in the HTTP cache on the way to the network.  If such a request is found, the browser always creates a conditional request to validate it even if it thinks that the response should be fresh.  If a matching cached entry is not found, a normal request will be made.  After a response has been downloaded, the HTTP cache will always be updated with that response.

`“force-cache”` means that the browser will always use a cached response if a matching entry is found in the cache, ignoring the validity of the response.  Thus even if a really old version of the response is found in the cache, it will always be used without validation.  If a matching entry is not found in the cache, the browser will make a normal request, and will update the HTTP cache with the downloaded response.

Let’s look at a few examples of how you can use these cache modes.

```
  // Download a resource with cache busting, to bypass the cache
  // completely.
  fetch("some.json", {cache: "no-store"})
    .then(function(response) { /* consume the response */ });

  // Download a resource with cache busting, but update the HTTP
  // cache with the downloaded resource.
  fetch("some.json", {cache: "reload"})
    .then(function(response) { /* consume the response */ });

  // Download a resource with cache busting when dealing with a
  // properly configured server that will send the correct ETag
  // and Date headers and properly handle If-Modified-Since and
  // If-None-Match request headers, therefore we can rely on the
  // validation to guarantee a fresh response.
  fetch("some.json", {cache: "no-cache"})
    .then(function(response) { /* consume the response */ });

  // Download a resource with economics in mind!  Prefer a cached
  // albeit stale response to conserve as much bandwidth as possible.
  fetch("some.json", {cache: "force-cache"})
    .then(function(response) { /* consume the response */ });
```

Comment: Hey, I am actually already sending the request without cache headers. Updated my question.

Comment: Still, request URL not hitting the server?

Comment: Yep, tried it with {cache: "no-store"}, nothing changed.